# Does creating a subarray use O(1) extra space in java

Tags: java, space-complexity

if there is given array, ex. arr

Java code:

```
int arr[] = {10,23,65,15,45};
int n = arr.length; //i.e n=5 
int k = 2;
int temp[] = new temp[k];
```

and if I create new array if size k which will be subarray of arr and will always have size less than original array arr.

Does this violate the condition of O(1) extra space?

Comment: If you create a new array of size `k` then it take O(k) space. How could it not?

Comment: if k is a constant known at compile time, then it's still O(1), if it depends on n then it's not, in which case you probably need to operate on the orginal array directly without creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you were creating a subarray (or [array slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing)) implemented as a reference to the original array (plus bounds) it would be an `O(1)` space overhead, irrespective of the size of the slice.

However, what you are creating (as `temp`) is not a subarray.  It is an independent array.

In this case your code will use `O(k)` extra space for `temp`.  If `k` is a constant (i.e. `2`) `O(K)` is the same<sup>1</sup> as `O(1)`.  But if `k` is a scaling variable, then `O(K)` is not reducible.

So ...

> Does this violate the condition of `O(1)` extra space?

Assuming `k` is a scaling variable, yes.

(And if `k` was a constant, and you did this a `N` times where `n` is a scaling variable, then you are allocating `O(k * N)` or `O(N)` extra space.)

---

Note that Java does not support array slices, but the `List` API allows you to create sublists (with an `O(1)` space overhead).

---

<sup>1 - From a mathematical perspective, `O(1)` is an infinite set of functions. `O(K)` where `K` is a constant is *the same* infinite set of functions as `O(1)`.</sup>